# Renewal of App Store Developer Contract (Paid Applications)

Tags: mac-appstore, developer-program

I've registered with Apple for a **Paid applications contract** about a year ago and the contract renewal is due in late June.

Since the initial application (registering as an individual) was done manually (and sent **via Fax** - as a Greek national), I'm not sure about the renewal process.

- Is the procedure *automatic*?
- Will I be notified (hopefully) in time by Apple itself so that I *resubmit* my initial subscription application or what?

Comment: I think this question is off topic if you check our [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq).
I flag the question in this sense.

Comment: @Ermiar I understand that. Any ideas where it might be **on**-topic? I really can't find an answer to this, anywhere...

Comment: I think you can ask the question on Stackoverflow, there are several question about Apple developer program. Hope this helps !

Comment: Since you are currently a developer, ask this from apple directly from the developer portal. Even if most developers don't have to renew each year, only Apple can tell you if you will need to do anything other than just pay to renew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry. You will receive instructions by email. You'll have to refill the form with your CC info and fax it again (I'm in BG, done this twice already).

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the US, and I've registered online. Contrary to what one might think, even online renewal is *not* automatic. I believe, as mspasov said, you should receive an email from Apple Developer with more information on renewal.